# Não consigo inicializar as Configurações do Automapper 6.2.2 Asp.netcore 2.0

Tags: ddd, automapper, asp.net-core

Na minha camada Application, tenho as seguintes classes:

```js
public class AutoMapperConfig
    {

        public static MapperConfiguration RegisterMappings()
        {
            return new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new DomainToViewModelMappingProfile());
                cfg.AddProfile(new ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile());
            });
        }
    }
```

```js
public class DomainToViewModelMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public DomainToViewModelMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

```js
public class ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public ViewModelToDomainMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, RegisterNewCustomerCommand>()
                .ConstructUsing(c => new RegisterNewCustomerCommand(c.Name, c.Email, c.BirthDate));
            CreateMap<CustomerViewModel, UpdateCustomerCommand>()
                .ConstructUsing(c => new UpdateCustomerCommand(c.Id, c.Name, c.Email, c.BirthDate));
        }
    }
```

Na minha camada Asp.net MVC, Tenho a classe Startup.cs que através do método  services.AddAutoMapper(); inicializa minhas classes de de configuração do Automapper, só que ele chama o método e não passa pelas classes citadas acima. Consequentemente, quando eu for mandar salvar algum registro no meu banco, acontece um erro na minha controller relacionado ao Automapper:

Erro: "+        $exception  {AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

## For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters

CustomerViewModel -> RegisterNewCustomerCommand (Destination member list)
SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.CustomerViewModel -> SistemaComercial.Domain.Commands.Customer.RegisterNewCustomerCommand (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Timestamp
ValidationResult
MessageType
AggregateId

at AutoMapper.ConfigurationValidator.AssertConfigurationIsValid(IEnumerable`1 typeMaps)
   at lambda_method(Closure , CustomerViewModel , RegisterNewCustomerCommand , ResolutionContext )
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object , ResolutionContext )
   at AutoMapper.Mapper.AutoMapper.IMapper.Map[TDestination](Object source)
   at SistemaComercial.Application.Services.CustomerAppService.Register(CustomerViewModel customerViewModel) in C:\Users\jalbe\Desktop\New_Project\SistemaComercial\src\SistemaComercial.Application\Services\CustomerAppService.cs:line 46
   at SistemaComercial.Presentation.Web.MVC.Controllers.CustomerController.Create(CustomerViewModel customerViewModel) in C:\Users\jalbe\Desktop\New_Project\SistemaComercial\src\SistemaComercial.Presentation.Web.MVC\Controllers\CustomerController.cs:line 62
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()}  AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException
"

```js
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddAutoMapper(); //Jalber

            // Adding MediatR for Domain Events and Notifications
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup)); //Jalber

            // .NET Native DI Abstraction
            RegisterServices(services); //Jalber
           

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Adding dependencies from another layers (isolated from Presentation)
            NativeInjectorBootStrapper.RegisterServices(services);
        }
    }
```

Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá @

Achei a solução para o problema.

Na classe Startup.cs, basta trocar:

*services.AddAutoMapper()*

por:

*services.AddAutoMapper(**Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutoMapperConfig))**);*

Aqui pra mim funcionou. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Lauro! No meu caso, o problema estava acontecendo com outro componente (AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) que eu estava instalando na versão mais recente e estava dando pau... Só foi eu instalar a versão 2.0.1 que resolveu....

Answer (score 0):

Desde a versão do curso do Eduardo Pires houveram mudanças no Automapper, que tornam a configuração mais fácil e legível. Vou demonstrar.

Primeiro crie a classe de perfil de mapeamento, assim como você fez, porém apenas uma, já que faremos uso do método `.ReverseMap()`, que já faz o mapeamento inverso dos objetos automaticamente.

```
public class MapProfile:AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public MapProfile()
        {
            // Core
            CreateMap<SchoolPrincipal, SchoolPrincipalViewModel>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

Depois, crie a classe que iniciará o Automapper na classe `Startup`

```
public class MapConfiguration
{
    public static void RegisterMapProfile()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile<MapProfile>();
        });
    }
}
```

Agora no método `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` da classe `Startup` inclua a linha:

```
MapConfiguration.RegisterMapProfile();
```

Comment: Saquei..... Muito bom!!!